# Unitary equivalence

Tags: matrices

How to show that: Let $A=QR$ be a $QR$ factorization, then $A$ is normal if and only if $Q$ and $R^*$ can be simultaneously diagonalized by unitary equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

The "if" part is trivial. The "only if" part, however, is not true in general. Here is a counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{5&2&-4\\ 2&8&2\\ -4&2&5}
=QR=
\pmatrix{
\tfrac{ 5}{\sqrt{45}} &0                 &\tfrac23\\
\tfrac{ 2}{\sqrt{45}} &\tfrac2{\sqrt{5}} &\tfrac{-1}3\\
\tfrac{-4}{\sqrt{45}} &\tfrac1{\sqrt{5}} &\tfrac23}
\pmatrix{
\tfrac5{\sqrt{45}}&\tfrac2{\sqrt{45}}&\tfrac{-4}{\sqrt{45}}\\
0&\tfrac2{\sqrt{5}}&\tfrac1{\sqrt{5}}\\
0&0&0}
$$
If $Q$ and $R^\ast$ are simultaneously diagonalisable, they must commute, i.e. $R^\ast Q-QR^\ast=0$. Yet, in this example, we have
$$
R^\ast Q-QR^\ast=9\sqrt{5}\pmatrix{8&-6&10\\ -4&3&-2\\ 8&-6&-11}\ne0.
$$